# How can I send ajax POST on browser?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to upload a video to server by jQuery ajax on my browser.
this is my request :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            url: uploadUrl,
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 6000000,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log("ERROR : ", e);
            }
        });
    });
```

**Error** :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.server.com' from origin 'http://192.168.1.4:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**Headers** :

**General :** 
**Request URL**: https://www.server.com
**Referrer Policy**: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

**Response Headers :**
**access-control-allow-credentials**: true
**cache-control**: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
**cache-control**: post-check=0, pre-check=0
**content-encoding**: gzip
**content-type**: text/plain; charset=utf-8
**date**: Tue, 01 Jun 2021 07:00:33 GMT 
**expires**: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
**last-modified**: Tue, 01 Jun 2021 07:00:33 GMT
**pragma**: no-cache
**referrer-policy**: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
**server**: nginx
**set-cookie**: playIconOnHover_1=old; path=/
**set-cookie**: AFCN=162253083336672; expires=Sun, 01-Jun-2031 07:00:33 GMT; Max-Age=315532800; path=/; domain=.server.com
**set-cookie**: PHPSESSID=APAf3-e162d2860b1219b0633755a88-302087; path=/
**set-cookie**: PHPSESSID=APAf3-e162d2860b1219b0633755a88-302087; expires=Mon, 30-Aug-2021 07:00:33 GMT; Max-Age=7776000; path=/ 
**set-cookie**: serverUid=84db2%2C302087; expires=Tue, 01-Jun-2021 11:00:33 GMT; Max-Age=14400; path=/; domain=.server.com 
**set-cookie**: apr_lb_id=m6; path=/; domain=.server.com 
**transfer-encoding**: chunked 
**vary**: Accept-Encoding 
**x-content-type-options**: nosniff 
**x-frame-options**: SAMEORIGIN 
**x-powered-by**: Server Framework/1.0.1 
**x-solr**: 0 
**x-solr-cnt**: 0 
**x-xss-protection**: 1; mode=block

**Request Headers :**
**Accept**: */*
**Accept-Encoding**: gzip, deflate, br 
**Accept-Language**: en-US,en;q=0.9 
**Connection**: keep-alive 
**Content-Length**: 1570763 
**Content-Type**: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 
**Host**: [www.server.com](http://www.server.com) 
**Origin**: http://192.168.1.4:3000 
**Referer**: http://192.168.1.4:3000/ 
**sec-ch-ua**: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90" 
**sec-ch-ua-mobile**: ?0 
**Sec-Fetch-Dest**: empty
**Sec-Fetch-Mode**: cors 
**Sec-Fetch-Site**: cross-site 
**User-Agent**: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36

Then I added this headers :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            url: uploadUrl,
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
            },
            cache: false,
            timeout: 6000000,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log("ERROR : ", e);
            }
        });
    });
```

**Error** :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.server.com' from origin 'http://192.168.1.4:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to **preflight** request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

then I tested jsonp :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            url: uploadUrl,
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            cache: false,
            timeout: 6000000,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log("ERROR : ", e);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**and Error** :

> jquery.min.js:2 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://www.server.com/?callback=jQuery360009544112228460921_1622530021674&_=1622530021675 with MIME type text/plain. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

Comment: You will find plenty of resources on how to fix any of those CORS errors if you search for the error messages

Comment: these headers are not for the ajax part. These are for the server side. Also note that adding a wildcard for CORS is a very bad idea. Restrict it to just the domains you need

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+cors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you have access to the .htaccess file, then adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` may work. Otherwise, they will generally have it set at `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: www.example.com`**

---

CORS is there for a reason, it's to block unauthorized people from accessing certain data or sending data to a certain place. 

Here is the description from Mozilla: 
Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is an HTTP-header based mechanism that allows a server to indicate any other origins (domain, scheme, or port) than its own from which a browser should permit loading of resources. CORS also relies on a mechanism by which browsers make a “preflight” request to the server hosting the cross-origin resource, in order to check that the server will permit the actual request. In that preflight, the browser sends headers that indicate the HTTP method and headers that will be used in the actual request.

An example of a cross-origin request: the front-end JavaScript code served from https://domain-a.com uses XMLHttpRequest to make a request for https://domain-b.com/data.json.

For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from scripts. For example, XMLHttpRequest and the Fetch API follow the same-origin policy. This means that a web application using those APIs can only request resources from the same origin the application was loaded from unless the response from other origins includes the right CORS headers.

Read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS